# SQL_INTERVAL_STRUCT fraction value

Tags: database, odbc, informix, unixodbc

I have been using the SQL_INTERVAL_STRUCT to fetch Interval data from an Informix database.  I have discovered that the fractional part of the Interval is expected to be in microseconds (rather than milliseconds).

Can anyone confirm if this is Informix specific behavior or if all ODBC drivers would make this same assumption about the fraction portion of an Interval.

Here is the definition of the struct:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711781(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find a definitive answer, but it seems likely given that the fractional part of a SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT is defined as being in microseconds (10e-9 sec).

But I agree, it seems strangely undefined. You can of course set the fractional precision in the data type, but that doesn’t alter the C structure representation. Or at least its not likely that it would, if the timestamp example is any guide.

Comment: microseconds are 10e-6, 10e-9 is nanoseconds.

I'm actually trying to figure out if there's any _definitive_ documentation, but our product's current interpretation of the spec is that the meaning of the fraction value in the C interval struct is actually dependent on the value of the `SQL_DESC_PRECISION` field in the ARD/APD when it's passed to or retrieved from the driver (and it's in units of 10e-<precision> seconds)

Comment: and the default value of the precision field, for interval types, is 6, so if the application doesn't override it, then it will *indeed* be in terms of microseconds